# Getting the second largest element lexicographically

Tags: java

I am trying to print the second largest element in the array lexicographically, or alphabetically. pop is indeed the second largest. however; my code is not designed the way I thought of when I test another set of arrays, apparently I'm only printing the last element. Any suggestions on where I went wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("bob");
    list.add("mill");
    list.add("sun");
    list.add("opera");
    list.add("bun");
    list.add("pop");
    System.out.println("list: " + list);
    String s = list.get(0);
    for ( int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
            s = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(i + 1));   
        } else if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) < 0) {
            s = list.get(i + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("second largest: " + s);
}
}
```

Comment: I edited the whitespace of your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Why are you changing the list itself?

Comment: changing the list? do you mean why am I adding to the list?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following pseudocode for printing the second largest element:

```
element largest = ""
element secondlargest = ""
for each element in list:
   if element > largest:
      secondlargest = largest
      largest = element
   else if element > secondlargest:
      secondlargest = element
print secondlargest
```

(If you wished to expand this to be able to print the third, fourth or nth element, a smarter approach would be better - in the extreme, you'd just create a sorted copy of the list and return the nth item from the end)

Comment: Thank you, I did the same thing with numbers, however; I guess I was having difficulties with strings.

Comment: @qvd It's the exact same pseudocode, except that you need to do lexicographical comparisons (compareTo and test the value, for example)